# In django how to iterate and populate selected options value

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class World(models.Model):
country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Language = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Populations = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app_one.models import World

def index(request):
countries = World.objects.order_by('country')
all_countries = {'list_countries':countries}
return render(request,'app_one/index.html',context=all_countries)
```

index.html

```
{% if list_countries %}
  <select>
    {% for li in list_countries %}
    <option value="{{ li.country }}">{{ li.country }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
    <p>"selected country's Language is "{{ li.language }}" </p>
    <p>"selected country's Population is "{{ li.populations }}" </p>
{% else %}
   <p>No suburbs found</p>
  {% endif %}
```

Once the country is selected by user I am not able to populate the language and population of the selected country.

Comment: are you trying to display the language and the population of the country in the html page after the user select the country ? if so then you need to use ajax to do that for you, notice that your codes have a lot of error. **context=all_countries** and in the html page {{ li.Language }} and {{ li.Populations }} . and as @parth mentioned you need to take care of li variable

Comment: Yes, the goal is to display language and population of the selected country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the language and population values in data attributes of the html option tags.

```
<select class="countries">
    {% for li in list_countries %}
    <option value="{{ li.country }}" data-population="{{ li.Population }}" data-language="{{ li.Language }}">{{ li.country }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<p>selected country's Language is <span class='selected-lang'></span></p>
<p>selected country's Population is <span class='selected-popu'></span></p>
```

And then using jquery

```
 $('.countries').change(function(){
    $self = $(this);
    $('.selected-lang').html($self.attr("data-language"));
    $('.selected-popu').html($self.attr("data-population"));
  });
```

Comment: Hi Rajat. How can I access these values if the  countries is used as a foreign key in ModelForm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128806/how-to-get-data-attributes-in-django-form-from-foreign-key

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Rajat Bulna
This is what helped me.

HTML

```
<select class="countries">
{% for li in list_countries %}
<option value="{{ li.country }}" data-population="{{ li.Population }}" data-language="{{ li.Language }}">{{ li.country }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<p>selected country's Language is <span class='selected-lang'></span></p>
<p>selected country's Population is <span class='selected-popu'></span></p>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.countries').change(function(){
       var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
      $('.selected-lang').html(selected.attr("data-language"));
      $('.selected-popu').html(selected.attr("data-population"));
    }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable you mention "li" it can be only used within forloop you can't use that outside the forloop. Extend the scope of your forloop to use 'li' variable in p tag

Comment: If i use the {% endfor %} after the end of p tag its giving me an error